# What is the meaning of Regular Expression [^\x7f]+

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

Could you please let me know, what is the meaning of the following regular expression

`[^\x7f]+`

Answer (score 1):

Matching any character other than the one with character code 7f